# pyglet - Smooth text rendering

Tags: python, pyglet

I've been looking on the internet for about an hour, and I can't seem to find a way to create smooth text.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
self.nameLabel = pyglet.text.Label(name, font_name='Tahoma', y=self.y + 6, font_size=12, batch=batch.overlay2, height=self.scale_y, bold=True)
```

And then I draw it using a batch:

```
batch.overlay2.draw()
```

The rendered text is not smooth, as shown in the following image:

[image]

How can I make this text look smoother?

Thanks in advance.

David

Comment: [https://bitbucket.org/pyglet/pyglet/issues/78/text-looks-terrible-or-doesnt-work-with](https://bitbucket.org/pyglet/pyglet/issues/78/text-looks-terrible-or-doesnt-work-with)... Maybe increasing font size to something like 14-18? Not sure if the way pyglet renders text is suitable for small fonts... although they claim in their website "pyglet provides the font module for efficiently rendering high-quality antialiased Unicode glyphs". If pyglet text rendering is not good enough for small fonts I suggest you google "sdf font rendering"

Comment: @BPL Yes I read that too "pyglet provides the font module for efficiently rendering high-quality antialiased Unicode glyphs". I'll try increase the font size and then scale the font down if possible.